# Derivative Explained

Tags: derivatives

$\frac{1}{\rho*c^2}*P*\frac{\partial P}{\partial t} = \frac{1}{\rho*c^2} *\frac{P^2}{2}*\frac{\partial}{\partial t} $

My professor did this derivative in class and I didn't quite understand it. I understand that the rho and c are held constant as well as nothing is differentiated with respect to time. However, I don't understand where the $1/2$ and $P^2$ come from.

Anything would help! Thanks.

Comment: The following makes sense : $\frac{1}{\partial t} \left(\frac {P^2}2\right) = P \frac{\partial P}{\partial t}$, where $P$ is a function of $t$. I don't see why the order of the partial derivative and $P$ is mixed in the RHS of the confusing line above. If the order was the other way then we would be fine.

Comment: Are you sure that the partial derivative goes last? The left hand side is a function and the right hand side is an operator. There equation simply isn't valid as written.

Comment: My apologies I forgot to add the partial over partial t on the right hand side of the equals sign. Does that clarify things?

Comment: The first comment here should be the right answer here. That's almost certainly what the formula was supposed to be.

Comment: Where does the two go in that case? Moving from the left side of the equals sign to the right.